# How to enable VSCode code suggestion (autocompletion) like WebStorm code suggestion?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I am looking for a way how can I enable all code suggestions for JavaScript, HTML, CSS, jQuery, Bootstap, React and etc. code. for example I write this same codes in Visual Studio Code and WebStorm, but as you seen the code suggestion result is different ( In addition I installed and enabled all nessery extensions for VSCode):

[image: VSCode]

[image: WebStorm]

In WebStorm I have all suggestion that match the word cli, but in VSCode there is no anyy code suggestion.

Comment: that are jQuery completions, if VSC is not jQuery aware you don't get suggestions

Comment: If no jQuery support in the Marketplace, it is a good time to write one yourself

Comment: did you install [`@types/jquery`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery)? VS Code doesn't bundle types packages for those libraries. You have to install them yourself, and you're better off doing that anyway.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed as looking for software recommendations. this question is on-topic. the only closure I'm interested in finding here is a dup-target.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I installed [@types/jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery?activeTab=readme) and also [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en) and the problem was solved. Thanks for your guidance [starball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11107541/starball)